# How to Execute MSCRM Workflow Asynchronously in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, dynamics-crm, workflow

Below is my `C#` snippet that triggers a `mscrm` `workflow`.

```
public void GenerateWorkflow(string selectedIDs, IOrganizationService service)
{
    var request = new OrganizationRequest()
    {
        RequestName = "GenerateWorkflow",
    };
    request.Parameters.Add("SelectedIDs", selectedIDs);

    var response = service.Execute(request);
    if (response.Results != null && response.Results.Count > 0)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

May I know how can I change the above execution to run from `sync` to `async`,  without having to wait for the response before executing the next request?

Thank you.

Comment: `Task.Run(() => GenerateWorkflow(...));` On a separate note, that if statement makes no sense as it stands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run `GenerateWorkflow` on a separate threadpool thread. You can call [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netcore-3.1)

> Queues the specified work to run on the ThreadPool and returns a task
> or `Task<TResult>` handle for that work.

```
Task.Run(() => GenerateWorkflow(...));
```

If you had several requests you wanted to run concurrently, and you wanted to wait for them to all finish, you could use [`Task.WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netcore-3.1).

> Creates a task that will complete when all of the supplied tasks have
> completed.

```
var task1 = Task.Run(() => GenerateWorkflow1(...)); 

var task2 = Task.Run(() => SomethingElse(...)); 

...

await Task.WhenAll(task1,task2,...);
```

Comment: Thank you @The General. May I know if `GenerateWorkflow` task can be executed multiple times with `Task.Run()`? Therefore, I will have multiple requests of `GenerateWorkflow`executed at the same time without requiring one completed, follow by another.

Comment: It depends on the api, but yes as far as c# is concerned it's fine

Answer (score 0):

try this class:"ExecuteAsyncRequest".
Pass an instance of this class to the Execute method, which returns an instance of ExecuteAsyncResponse.
just like this:service.ExecuteAsyncRequest(request);